# Creating shapefile of a raster image in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, raster-conversion, vectorization

I use QGIS 3.6 on Windows and I have been trying to convert raster images into shapefiles. I managed to do that for Digital Terrain Models only, using the conversion --> vectorize tool in the qgis toolbar.

An example of images I want to convert into shapefile can be found in this link https://www.uahirise.org/ESP_040921_1985. How do I achieve that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by converting an image into a shapefile?

Comment: My supervisor is requesting these files in shapefile format because I have more than 100 raster HiRISE images that are more than 150 Gb. This size cannot be uploaded in a google drive or dropbox so he requested shapefiles. I told him that I did not manage to do that but he did not give any advice.

Comment: So, you want to share this data? You could convert it to eg. `.png` and reduce the resolution.

Comment: Yes I need to share them and he requested shapefiles. I tried the vectorize tool as I did with the DTMs but it was empty.  How can I convert to png?

Comment: `Raster - Conversion - Translate`

Comment: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: Well, the translate tool did not help as the converted image was still 2.95 Gb.

Comment: Where do I type a similar code like the one in the link pasted above?           
`gdal_translate                                                                                                                  -co COMPRESS=JPEG \                                                                                                  -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR \                                                                                    -co TILED=YES                                                                                               
 5255C.tif 5255C_JPEG_YCBCR.tif`